# How to refresh data in p:dataTable, preserving filter and sorting?

Tags: jsf, sorting, primefaces

How to refresh data in **PrimeFaces DataTable** preserving **filtering** and **sorting** options?

The DataTable is handling filtering internally, so after refresh data in backing bean the changes are yet not visible, it is necessary to invoke filter() on dataTable in JavaScript. At least in my case. Afterwards, the data are filtered, but they are not sorted! However, the styles on the column header are left, so the column is displayed as sorted, which is confusing to the end user (for him, it's a bug).

The dataTable has also a sort() function, but invoking it is causing an error:

```
TypeError: f is undefined
```

so it seems it's not the correct way of handling that case...

The official documentation is silent in that case, but the refresh button is the common case. Additionally the data should be auto-refreshed in my case, and the sorting and filtering shouldn't change.

So, how to re-sort the DataTable after data refresh? How to avoid writing the sort myself in backing bean and re-use PrimeFaces sorting?

Comment: use `filteredValue` attribute of the datatable http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf , sorting  can be preserved if you use lazy loading data model (I think...)

Comment: filteredValue is used only for storing temporary data, isn't it? with lazy loading it could work, but I would like to reusing the PrimeFaces sorting which, without refreshing, is working fine for me, and not writing it myself (writing all yourself makes no sense using frameworks ;)

Comment: `filteredValue` stores filtered values